# Android linear layout set visibility in a listview custom adapter

Tags: android-layout, android-listview

last time i had problem with setting radio button checked of particular row of custom adapter because of listview recycling of view after scrolling up / down and i had solved it using set tag and get tag to the radio button, but this time i am trying this for a linear layout having 2 buttons to set visibility but m ending up with crash.Reason being is i am not unable to cast integer to a linear layout, so please help me how to work with linear layout.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.list_item_agents_feed, null);
        holder.agentBhkTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feedBhkTv);
        holder.chatLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chatLayout);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    final AgentsFeedData data = agentsFeedDataList.get(position);
    holder.agentChatBtn.setTag(position);
    if (data.getUsername() != null) {
        if (data.getUsername().equals(uname)) {
            holder.chatLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) holder.agentBhkTv.getTag();
            holder.chatLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
```

crash log is

```
08-03 22:09:58.603  28409-28409/in.pm.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout
        at in.pm.android.adapter.AgentsFeedAdapter.getView(AgentsFeedAdapter.java:103)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2627)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1852)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:682)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:748)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1653)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2447)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1076)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15204)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4793)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1677)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1531)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1440)
```

the line where it crashes is

```
holder.chatLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) holder.agentBhkTv.getTag();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer after looking into how other data was perfectly getting displayed.
K after studying the type of data i was setting to adapter ie using arraylist with an Object class having getter and setter then i did this, hope this might help others facing same problem.

```
public class AgentsFeedData {
    private String bhk;
    private boolean visible = true;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getBhk() {
        return bhk;
    }

    public void setBhk(String bhk) {
        this.bhk = bhk;
    }

    public boolean isVisible() {
        return visibile;
    }

    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        this.visible = visible;
    }
}
```

the usage of code in adapter class

```
public class AgentsFeedAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<AgentsFeedData> agentsFeedDataList = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context mContext;

public AgentsFeedAdapter(Context mContext, List<AgentsFeedData> agentsFeedDataList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.agentsFeedDataList = agentsFeedDataList;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.list_item_agents_feed, null);
        holder.agentBhkTv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feedBhkTv);
        holder.agentChatBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.agentChatBtn);
        holder.agentConnectBtn = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.agentConnectBtn);
        holder.chatLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chatLayout);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    final AgentsFeedData data = agentsFeedDataList.get(position);
    String uname = mContext.getSharedPreferences(Constansts.PREFERENCE_NAME, 0)
            .getString(Constansts.USER_ID, "");
    if (data.getUsername() != null) {
        if (data.getUsername().equals(uname)) {
            data.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    if (!data.isVisible()){
        holder.chatLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        holder.chatLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    return convertView;
}

public void swapItems(List<AgentsFeedData> agentsFeedDataList) {
    this.agentsFeedDataList = agentsFeedDataList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private class ViewHolder {
    TextView agentBhkTv;
    Button agentChatBtn;
    Button agentConnectBtn;
    LinearLayout chatLinearLayout;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `holder.chatLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) holder.agentChatBtn.getTag();` line at all. If on the `convertView == null` case -> you are setting it right there, a few lines above. If on the else branch, your `holder.chatLinearLayout` is already being set when you created the view in the first place. Just remove that whole line.

Comment: Ya removing that it doesn't crash but what i need is to set visibility of chat layout for some rows to be invisible depending on data, at first for the number of visible rows in my screen it works properly but once i scroll to bottom and come back, then visibility for chat layout of other rows are affected, i mean its visible for those rows where it was not supposed to be visible and vice versa.

Comment: Your list item view is being recycled and you need to set its properties every time in getView(). If you don't then it will keep the properties from the previous usage.
So you need to write something like:
`if (data.getUsername() != null && data.getUsername().equals(uname))
 holder.chatLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
else
 holder.chatLinearLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
`

Comment: To be more clear: imagine that your are in getView() setting up a view that is supposed to be `visible`, but it was recycled from a view that was `gone` before. If you don't explicitly set it back to `visible`, it will stay `gone`.

Comment: At first i had used this code, after several items in list it started becoming a mess, so it didn't work out. And in my case
(data.getUsername() != null && data.getUsername().equals(uname)) was giving true but i was not saving for which position of list view this value was true so when that particular position comes back i can make it work with saved value.